# Light Box not opening when Clicking on image (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress plugin [Category Grid View Gallery](http://wordpress.org/plugins/category-grid-view-gallery/) But when I am clicking on any image, it is opening but image is not displayed.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: http://www.knittedfittedbedsheets.com/products-2/jacquard-terry-fitted-sheets/
that's my page

Comment: which is the lighbox plugin your using??

Comment: Category Grid View Gallery check comment i have put link and plugin name

Comment: can you tell me the version of plugin and the shortcode you're using???

Comment: [cgview id=category&tag_ID=42 num=2  size=275x250] this is my shortcode and using "Category Grid View Gallery v2.3.3"

Comment: [cgview num=9 id=4 size=250x150] try with this shortcode...

Comment: Check the Console there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using **id** attribute 2 times.

Try below code, make changes with your needs

```
[cgview id=9 num=33 size=320x320 quality=85 lightbox=0]
```

Attribute of `lightbox=0` is for those who want to get the image instead of the post. If you don't want remove this.

Comment: i want to open lightbox it taking on post can i open lightbox image ?

Comment: yes by including `lightbox=0` attribute it opens image in lightbox, instead of post.

Comment: [cgview id=64  num=33 size=356x432 quality=85]

[cgview id=64 num 33 size=356x432 quality=85 lightbox=0]